# What is the best way of storing info without using external database or table?

Tags: c#

Ok, so what I need to is something simple at first look. I have a win app with a text box, lets say TextBox1.

I want to return a value based on what the user writes in the box like this: I have 100 values with a corresponding text that I want to display.

- For value "Dan" in textbox i want to display "Text 1" in another box
- For "Jake" i want "Text 2"

and so on. I already have this correspondence in an excel table so I know what to display but to make 100 if clauses or cases it's not that pretty.

Anyway I can store this list in the app and just do a lookup or something and the the right value?

EDIT 1: Based on Hogan's reply.

I created a button and used it to create the dictionary and insert 2 values in the dictionary.
I created another button to retrieve the value from dictionary.

It works only if I add the values and retrieve them in the same run. If i close the app and try and retrieve the dictionary is empty.

EDIT 2: Hogan's solution.
I declared the dictionary as public.

```
    Dictionary<string, string> myLookup;
```

I added the dictionary creation in the button code:

```
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        myLookup.Add("Dan", "Text 1");
        myLookup.Add("Jake", "Text 2");
    }
```

And i created another button to get the data:

```
    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myLookup["Dan"]);
    }
```

If i click the first button to add the data and then the second to retrieve it works. If i close the app and reopen, and click directly the second one, it doesn't work.

EDIT 3: I went with external file, Steve's solution. Since the "no external file" solution is too hard to make (too many rows of code to write down).

Comment: Does this need to be persistent? I.e. when you restart the application, do you expect the values to be still there?

Comment: Yes, that's my issue. I want to be able to set it once and have it available when i restart the app.

Comment: Will the `100 values with a corresponding text` ever change? - Will any of the values, or their text change?

Comment: Yes, i might have to change them sometimes. Add few, change some, delete few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load your data from the Excel file and fill a Dictionary object where the Key is your Excel first column and the Value is the Excel second column

```
 string excelCnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                        @"Data Source=ExcelFile.xlsx;" + 
                        @"Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0'"; 
 Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>()
 using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(excelCnString))
 using(OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet$]", cn))
 {
      cn.Open();
      using(OleDbDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
      {
          dict.Add(reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString());
      }
 }
```

Now you could use the dictionary simply as

```
 if(dict.ContainsKey(textBox1.Text))
     textBox2.Text = dict[textBox1.Text];
```

In this way the data is external to your application. This means that you or your user could change it using Excel. In every case you read that data when you app starts. Of course this means that you need to distribute the Excel file with your app, but has the advantage to be easy to modifiy the contents of the file at your will.

Of course you could provide an interface to change your data. In that case your need also a method to save the data back into the Excel file.

Something like this could do the work

```
 string excelCnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                        @"Data Source=ExcelFile.xlsx;" + 
                        @"Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0'"; 

 using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(excelCnString))
 using(OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet$] SET COLUMN2 = @V1 WHERE COLUMN1 = @V2", cn))
 {
      cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("V1", string.Empty);
      cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("V2", string.Empty);
      cn.Open();
      foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in dict)
      {
          cmd1.Parameters["V1"] = kvp.Value;
          cmd1.Parameters["V2"] = kvp.Key;
          cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
 }
```

Comment: I tried that, but i need the excel to be available at each app load. I don't want to depend on external files

Comment: This means that your data is fixed? If you don't want to depend on external files then you have no way to change that data and persist them for the next run.

Comment: I might have to change it from time to time, but i dont want to load it every time from an external file.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to be able to change that data. But if you don't store it somewhere. Then, when you run again your app, how do you suppose to retrieve the last change applied? You need an external file to persist the changes and read them back. So, why not to start directly with an external file with the initial data? I can only suppose that you don't want anyone look at the data, but once the app is on the user machine there is little that you can do to hide this info.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. But i wanted to ask, maybe there is some other way :(

Comment: @Steve - you are right.  A configuration file and a DB are conceptually the same here.  So the choice is -- compile the values into the application and re-compile for changes or use external file / db.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you are looking for a data structure called a dictionary -- that is you have a key that looks up to a value.

A dictionary can be stored in the DB (as a table) or it can be stored in memory.  You could for example do this:

```
   Dictionary<string,string> myLookup = new Dictionary<string,string>();

   myLookup.Add("Dan","Text 1");
   myLookup.Add("Jake","Text 2");
```

Once myLookup variable is available to code you could find the value to display with a simple lookup (it acts like an array) `myLookup[TextBox1.Text]`

Comment: So by adding this dictionary the data will be stored "in" the app?

Comment: Yes it will be compiled into the application.  You could also add it to a configuration file, but that is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: @Danut, Note that using a `Dictionary` will not preserve the data when the application is closed.

Comment: @ebb - what do you mean -- if the initialization of the data is compiled into the application code then it is preserved.  Do you mean dynamic changes to the dictionary won't be saved?

Comment: Ok, so i will have to code the addition of the dictionary elements in my app, and add them each time the app loads. Not really what i need.

Comment: @Hogan, I assumed that the data would be dynamic, but reading the question, I see that it is static. - Then indeed a dictionary would be  a way of doing it.

Comment: @Danut - I'm not sure why this is not what you need -- can you explain where it is not what you need?

Comment: @Hogan - I understood from the above comments that the data would not be stored when the app is restarted. If i understood incorrectly, and the data is available after the app is closed and opened again, then this is indeed what i need.

Comment: @Danut - The data would be available after the app is restarted ebb's first statement is wrong as he said in a later comment

Comment: Doesn't work. I need to add the values at each load, otherwise they are not there if i close and start the app again.

Comment: @Danut -- never mind I read your note and understand... the issue is you have the adding tied to the button -- just take out the button and put the adding to dictionary in the initialization code of the form.

Comment: Yeah, but in this way i will have to add all 100 or more records to the dictionary each time. Better retrieve them from external file :)

Comment: @Danut - your original question asked how to do it without an external file or DB -- this is how.  I agree it is an ugly solution but that would be how to do it.

Comment: Correct. It an excelent solution. and i still cannot decide if to use this or external file :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want this information to be permanently available, I would suggest you store it in App.config, and use the ConfigurationManager class to look up the values. This would be fairly simple to implement.