# How to update excel file data using row and column in C# using OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, excel

I am have created some function to read data form excel file using, OleDbConnection, OleDbDataAdapter, DataSet. I am able to read data successfully using sheet name, row, column number.

I function using same to update value of excel sheet by passing row and column number.

I need some help,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592501/what-is-the-best-way-of-storing-info-without-using-external-database-or-table/22592617#22592617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a strong reason for using OleDb for this, I recommend against it.  The usage is very limited and archaic and the providers are no longer shipped with Office 2013 or in Windows.  NuGet EPPlus and make your life a lot easier.

However, here is an example of how to do an insert and update using OleDb:

```
        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [MySheet$] (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) VALUES ('Count', 1);", cn))
            {
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [MySheet$] SET COLUMN2 = 5 WHERE ID = 1", cn))
            {
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, I have no unique key where I can use where condition, can update value only based ob row and column

Comment: There is a special column named ID, which holds the row number.  I have updated my example to update based off of this.  I do not believe you can select ID as a column in a select statement, even though it can be used in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks mikdav, your explanation in details, I will work in accordingly.